# Ever multiple socket connections for one HTTP request?

Tags: node.js, http

I'm working on a zero-downtime update/clustering server. Essentially, the server is always listening on port 80 and 443. When it gets a request, that request is piped to a child node instance that is listening on other ports (may or may not be on the same server). When we do an update, we just spin up more children with the new code and start piping new requests to those. When the old children are done handling their requests, they close themselves.

My question is: Is there ever a HTTP(S) request that would be broken up over multiple connections? Maybe something like a large file broken into chunks with each chunk closing the previous connection and creating a new one for the new chunk? This could potentially end up going to different servers and never get joined back together.

I'm just talking about the standard GET/POST/PUT/DELETE and file upload. To my understanding, these requests all take one connection. Maybe information is sent over multiple packets, but all information is sent over the one connection, yes?

Thanks!

Comment: yes, it's entirely possible. e.g. byte serving via GET, where you request a range of bytes. each range can be its own independent http request. e.g. request bytes 1-10 on monday, request bytes 11-20 on tuesday, and bytes 21-9999999 on wednesday when next month's data cap limit kicks in.